# How to use ridge.cv in R?

Tags: r, ridge-regression

I'm trying to use the ridge.cv() function in R. The [documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/parcor/docs/ridge.cv) says that the input y is the "vector of responses".

What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

ridge.cv() is not in base R, so I can't see the help file you are refering to without knowing the package you have loaded.  However, by convention y should be the variable you want to predict (typically a dependent variable).